# Ionic 6 storage (Indexed DB) clear

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, indexeddb

I can clear indexedDB (which is called in Ionic as storage) but when it is cleared in storage size is not reduced. I want to delete the entire Db from the indexed DB. below is the method which I tried.

```
acceptOrder{
   this.storage.clear();
}
```

[image: Index DB size]

Answer (score 0):

`Storage.clear()` is the correct method to di that.
Sometimes you have to reload Indexed-DB in browser console to see edits.

After you do clear, you can get values from DB?

Comment: I can clear data from indexedDB but in chrome, the size is not reduced. Once I clear the indexedDB, I wan to reduce the size also